# Database table join not returning proper result

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have following table:

**MovieMaster:**

[image]

**DVDBinSlotInfo:**

[image]

There can be repeated movieid in DVDBinSlotInfo table.

I just want to take them differently through query,

i.e.

Movienames which are not repeated for particular kioskid and

Movienames which are repeated for particular kioskid

for this i made following query:

```
select MovieName  from MovieMaster where MovieID in(select MovieID from DVDBinSlotInfo 

where KioskID='901' and Status='DVD' )
```

above was for all movieids

below is for distinct (not repeated):

```
select MovieName  from MovieMaster where MovieID in(select distinct MovieID from 

DVDBinSlotInfo where KioskID='901' and Status='DVD' )
```

but unfortunatly , with both the queries it shows Movienames which are not repeated for particular kioskid .

I want to show for repeated movieids also.

Means for example movieid 10 is reapeated thrice in DVDBinSlotInfo then it should show its name thrice in the result.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use INNER JOIN, (I guess)...

```
SELECT MovieName from MovieMaster 
INNER JOIN DVDBinSlotInfo ON MovieMaster.MovieId = DVDBinSlotInfo.MovieId
WHERE KioskID='901' and Status='DVD'
```